# Which system was used to create the document: LaTeX, WYSIWYG, etc

Tags: pdf, books

I have a PDF document. How do I know with the help of which the system was made the source text of the document: LaTeX, WYSIWYG (MS Word or LibreOffice, for example), etc?
I am interested in the details, which can be 90% state guarantee, that this book was in LaTeX are laid out, for example.
I hope that the question is clear. Thank you.

Comment: acrobat and many other pdf viewers have a properties menu which usually shows what software made the pdf, or the pdfinfo commandline utility will show the same information. (the question is really about pdf and off topic here)

Comment: Thanks. And if I know the ISBN of the book, if I can somehow find a system of production of its source code.

Comment: no, not unless the publisher says what that is in the front or back of the book, or you email them and ask them.